# What is the wrong with this algorithm for ensuring the critical section isn't interupted?

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, language-agnostic, deadlock, race-condition

From [here](http://crystal.uta.edu/~ylei/cse6324/data/critical-section.pdf)

> The global variable turn is used to indicate the next process to enter
>   the critical section. The initial value of turn can be 0 or 1.

`int turn = 1;`

**T0:**

```
while (true) {
  while (turn != 0) { ; } (1)
  critical section (2)
  turn = 1; (3)
  non-critical section (4)
}
```

**T1:**

```
while (true) {
  while (turn != 1) { ; } (1)
  critical section (2)
  turn = 0; (3)
  non-critical section (4)
}
```

[image: screen shot of solution to problem I don't get]

I don't understand what the problem is. Why would T0 repeat `while (turn != 1)` forever? If the context switches to T1 then it will enter it's critical section then set `turn=0`.

EDIT: I see now why T0 will wait forever. Is there a name to the "rule" that's being violated? For example in the context of threads there's "**mutual exclusion**", "**progress**", "**bounded waiting**" and "**No assumptions about relative speed of threads/processes**" so is one of these not being met?

Comment: According to the comment at T1(4), T1 isn't around anymore.  It terminated for an otherwise unspecified reason.  So it can never set *turn* back to 0.  Thus T0 gets stuck forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the second assumption in the problem description:
a thread may terminate in the non-critical section. The description you copied here specifies "T1 terminates in non-critical section", so that T1 will never set turn=0 anymore.